# How to resolve this mysql error #1093 - You can't specify target table 'person' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to delete some records from the table. I have written the following query

```
DELETE from person where name= (SELECT isFatherOf FROM person where name= 'bob')
```

It is giving me the following error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'person' for update in FROM clause
> I tried the solution from other similar questions and wrote this query:

```
     DELETE from person,
    (SELECT isFatherOf FROM person where name= 
    (SELECT isFatherOf FROM person WHERE name='Jane')) as father
  WHERE person.name= father.name
```

But the above query is again giving a different error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT isFatherOf FROM person where name= (SELECT isFatherOf FROM person WHERE ' at line 1

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE p1
FROM person p1
JOIN ( SELECT isFatherOf 
       FROM person 
       WHERE name= 'bob' ) p2 ON p1.name = p2.isFatherOf
```

[DELETE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) -> "Multiple-Table Syntax"